# Deny DeleteObject with a specific tag value in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I stumbled upon the following problem: I cannot create a bucket policy which denies objects deletion with object having a specific tag value.

By trying to create a statement like this:

```
{
    "Sid": "Stmt1234",
    "Action": "s3:DeleteObject",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Resource": [
         "arn:aws:s3:::foo/*",
         "arn:aws:s3:::foo"
     ],
     "Principal": "*",
     "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
            "s3:ExistingObjectTag/DoNotDelete": "true"
         }
     }
}
```

I get this error:

```
Conditions do not apply to combination of actions and resources in statement
```

However, if I change `Action` to, say, `s3:DeleteObjectTagging`, the policy becomes valid. I guess it is because of the restrictions about which conditions can be used with specific actions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html

**Is any way to create such a policy?**

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at [Actions, Resources, and Condition Keys for Amazon S3 - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazons3.html), you'll see that:

- `DeleteObjectTagging` has a condition key available of `s3:ExistingObjectTag/<key>`
- `DeleteObject` does not have a tag-related condition key

You can only use a `Condition` in the policy where the condition is listed for that particular action.

Comment: So there is no way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

s3:ExistingObjectTag is not available for s3:DeleteObject action. I prefer you using the Global condition key named "aws:TagKeys" such as:

```
{
    "Sid": "Stmt1234",
    "Action": "s3:DeleteObject",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Resource": [
         "arn:aws:s3:::foo/*",
         "arn:aws:s3:::foo"
     ],
     "Principal": "*",
     "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
            "aws:TagKeys": "DoNotDelete"
         }
     }
}
```

Hope, it helps.