# Protecting AWS resources based on Tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm trying to protect my AWS resources through a tag (without values)

Below is the example snippet of the IAM policy that I am using.

This doesn't seem to work!

```
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Sid": "ProtectResource",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:TagKeys": "ProtectionTag"
                }
            }
        }
```

If I change "StringEquals" to "ForAllValues:StringEquals", then it works but the protection stays even when the tag is removed.

Can you help me construct a condition that helps me protect the resource based on a tag alone. Optionally, I am fine with providing values if that is required to construct the condition.

Thanks.

Comment: SOme thing like this ?

    "Condition": {  "StringEquals": {"s3:ExistingObjectTag/tag key": "your tag value" }
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60273667/13126651

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I can confirm that did not work.
See my comments on the thread you shared.

Answer (score 5):

There is very often a misunderstanding/misconception about the differences between `aws:TagKeys`, `aws:RequestTag` and `aws:ResourceTag` regarding when they apply and *what* they apply *for*.

`aws:TagKeys` (only tag names) and `aws:RequestTag` (tag name/value pairs) is used to control access to API actions that carry tags in the request itself such as for modifying tags on a resource, in order to specify which tags (in the request itself) can be used with such an API action.

On the other hand, `aws:ResourceTag` is used to authorize API actions depending on the tag already present *on the resource itself*. So, if you want to specify a policy with a permission and that permission should only apply for resources that *have* a specific tag, then use `aws:ResourceTag` as the condition.

Having said this, the particular action `s3:DeleteObject` does not currently support resource-based tag conditions. So even though you can tag S3 objects, you cannot currently authorize API actions based on those resource tags.

Similar answer: [Deny DeleteObject with a specific tag value in S3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56865679/deny-deleteobject-with-a-specific-tag-value-in-s3-bucket#answer-56866158)

Comment: That helps. I was originally trying to do this on ec2 resources and translated it to an s3 example. ec2:ResourceTag fit the purpose as you rightly pointed out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, you can't do this. [DeleteObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html) **does not support** any conditions based on tags. The supported conditions keys are in the screenshot:

[image]

Some workarounds are **enabling versioning** in the bucket, or if the entire bucket is critical you can use [MFA delete](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/MultiFactorAuthenticationDelete.html) protection.